# How to load hunspell dictionary in Windows path with non-ASCII characters?

Tags: winapi, non-ascii-characters, hunspell

How to load hunspell dictionary in Windows path with non-ASCII characters?

[Hunspell manual](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/disco/en/man3/hunspell.3.html) suggests:

> In  WIN32
>          environment,  use  UTF-8  encoded  paths  started with the long path prefix \?\ to handle
>          system-independent character encoding and very long path names, too.

So I have code to do the following:

```cpp
QString spell_aff = QStringLiteral(R"(\\?\%1%2.aff)").arg(path, newDict);
QString spell_dic = QStringLiteral(R"(\\?\%1%2.dic)").arg(path, newDict);
// while normally not a an issue, you can't mix forward and back slashes with the prefix
spell_dic = spell_aff.replace(QChar('/'), QStringLiteral("\\"));
spell_dic = spell_dic.replace(QChar('/'), QStringLiteral("\\"));

qDebug() << "right before Hunspell_create";
mpHunspell_system = Hunspell_create(spell_aff.toUtf8().constData(), spell_dic.toUtf8().constData());
qDebug() << "right after Hunspell_create";
```

This prefixes `\\?\` to the path, uses a consistent directory separator as documented by the note in [microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/naming-a-file#maximum-path-length-limitation), and converts it to UTF-8 encoding with [.toUtf8()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#toUtf8).

Yet running the code out on Windows 10 Pro fails:

[image: Hunspell loading from path with non-ASCII characters fails]

How to fix?

Using Qt5, MinGW 7.3.0.

I've also done due research and as far as I can see, LibreOffice does the same thing and it seemingly works for them: [sspellimp.cxx](https://github.com/LibreOffice/core/blob/master/lingucomponent/source/spellcheck/spell/sspellimp.cxx#L305), [lingutil.hxx](https://github.com/LibreOffice/core/blob/master/lingucomponent/source/lingutil/lingutil.hxx#L35), and [lingutil.cxx](https://github.com/LibreOffice/core/blob/master/lingucomponent/source/lingutil/lingutil.cxx#L52).

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196408/discussion-on-question-by-vadim-peretokin-how-to-load-hunspell-dictionary-in-win).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [GetShortPathNameW](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-getshortpathnamew) to obtain a pure-ASCII path that Hunspell will understand. See [QTIFW-175](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTIFW-175) for an example.

(thanks to [Windows directory that will never contain non-ASCII characters for temp file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57112274/windows-directory-that-will-never-contain-non-ascii-characters-for-temp-file?noredirect=1#comment100764239_57112274))